# Errors with sentimentr

Tags: r

When trying to analyse some sentences using a custom lexicon with the same structure of those present on the CRAN pages, I get the following error:

```
> sentiment(sentences, polarity_dt =data.table(lexicon$V1, lexicon$V6))

Error in sentiment.get_sentences_character(frasi, polarity_dt = data.table(lexicon$V1,  : 
  `polarity_dt` & `valence_shifters_dt` not mutually exclusive
```

What does it mean?

This is the structure of the lexicon:

```
 > class(lexicon)
    [1] "data.frame"
```

This is a screenshot of the heading and the first rows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOCry.png

I would also like to have a separate analysis but based on topics, do you have any advice on that?

Thanks to everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as a fix for your error, check out the documentation for as_key here: [as_key function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sentimentr/versions/2.7.1/topics/as_key).

It's most likely that you need to include the comparison and sentiment attributes of the as_key function.

```
sentiment(sentences, polarity_dt = data.table(lexicon$V1, lexicon$V6),
          comparison = lexicon::hash_valence_shifters,
          sentiment = TRUE)
```

I was getting a similar error, and this worked for me.